# Natural sort from Lazarus in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, debian, freebsd, lazarus, natural-sort

I have found naturalstrcmp function in Linux and I think it is what I need. Any example of how to use it in Ubuntu, Debian and FreeBSD? Should I declare it as external?

EDIT: What is the libname I should put in my external declaration?
On my Debian 7.7 it is on /usr/share/man/man3/naturalstrcmp.3.gz from Alliance package.

I tried :

function naturalstrcmp(s, t: PChar): Integer; external 'alliance' name 'naturalstrcmp';

without success. The error message says that "cannot find -lalliance".

EDIT2: Now  I know that lib file is on /usr/lib/alliance/, but don't know the name of the lib. All files on that directory are named as libAbc.so.

So I tried:

function naturalstrcmp(s, t: PChar): Integer; external 'libMut.so' name 'naturalstrcmp';

but when I declare this function, the debugger returns an error condition.

http://postimg.org/image/ty2kn3yvp/

Comment: [http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,24450.msg147208.html#msg147208](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,24450.msg147208.html#msg147208). Or, [https://github.com/cooljeanius/doublecmd/blob/master/src/udcutils.pas](https://github.com/cooljeanius/doublecmd/blob/master/src/udcutils.pas) where function `CompareStrings` uses function `StrFloatCmpW` for natural comparision.

Comment: Answering to your question: yes, you should to declare any external functions as `external` (if it is not declared already in the RTL/FCL/LCL).

Comment: Sorry, but I need a system/language-aware function.

Comment: Should this be enough?

function naturalstrcmp(s1, s2 :string): integer; external name 'naturalstrcmp';

Comment: I found [this page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/3/NATURALSTRCMP/) about `naturalstrcmp` function. I not found anything about `mut.h`. So I can not provide library name. Your declaration must be `function naturalstrcmp(s, t: PChar): Integer; external 'dynlybname' name 'naturalstrcmp';` where 'dynlybname' is the library name where this function is realized. Siple test is `naturalstrcmp(PChar('a2'), PChar('a03'));`

Comment: And what is the library where this function is realized? dynlibname?

Comment: The package is in /usr/share/man/man3/naturalstrcmp.3.gz

Comment: I've no such manual page in my freebsd (It is a bit older though). Googling seems to indicate it is not POSIX (yet) and thus not portable.

Comment: http://manned.org/naturalstrcmp/e011433d

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `mut.h` include file comes from [Alliance](http://www-soc.lip6.fr/recherche/cian/alliance/) CAD software ([alternative link](https://soc-extras.lip6.fr/en/alliance-abstract-en/)). There are packages for various Linux distros and even a FreeBSD port (cad/alliance). You can try to install it and then look into `share/doc/alliance-5.0/` for further instructions on how to use it and link with it.